# Mongoose & getting timestamps of populated documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
const queryOptions = {
  populate: { path: 'createdBy', select: 'username updatedAt createdAt timestamps' },
  limit: options.limit,
  skip: (options.page - 1) * options.limit,
  sort: undefined as any
};

const query = {};

await Comment.find(query, null, queryOptions)
```

The issue is that I need the timestamp of when the user was last modified as part of this query, but there are no `createdAt` or `updatedAt` fields being returned.

Can anyone suggest how to get the updatedAt field value as part of populating field?